# Android Studio not syncing some files to Github repo

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github

I'm trying to get my Android Studio project to sync to a Github repo. I used the 'Share Project on Github' option to create the repo, and everything seemed to work fine except it appears only certain parts of the project were uploaded. The 'layout' files sync correctly, but the main java files of the project do not appear to. When I download the zip of the project, the folder where they should be is empty.

Additionally, my version control tab constantly shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTVzn.png), but when I attempt to push gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7PGD.png) error.

I've tried to manually add the java folder, the com.user folder, and the java files themselves by right clicking and pressing add, when when I do that **nothing happens and the add option does not blank out.**

Comment: https://github.com/jezza97/simple-draw  Link to the Github

Comment: Can you please not downvote without at least commenting why you downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Check your .gitignore file, ensure it doesn't have entries for the items that are not being pushed.

Try pushing the files from the bash prompt:

```
git -a -m "commit msg";
git push;
```